# Что означают показатели SMART? Винчестер скоро "умрет"?

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, hdd, диск, smart

Насколько критичны показатели винчестера?

Вывод команды `smartctl --all /dev/sda`:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [i686-linux-4.4.0-119-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi Deskstar 7K3000
Device Model:     Hitachi HDS723020BLA642
Serial Number:    MN1221F308SPPD
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 369c3fbef
Firmware Version: MN6OA180
User Capacity:    2 000 398 934 016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Apr 10 15:43:40 2018 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (22085) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 368) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   095   095   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       65550
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   136   136   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       81
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   139   139   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       389 (Average 438)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1307
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   133   133   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       27
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       7354
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1016
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1314
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1314
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   157   157   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 15/41)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7350 hours (306 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 5c a4 66 40 07  Error: ICRC, ABRT 92 sectors at LBA = 0x074066a4 = 121661092

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  35 00 00 00 65 40 e0 08      00:14:13.593  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 61 40 e0 08      00:14:13.588  WRITE DMA EXT
  ea 00 00 ff 60 40 a0 08      00:14:13.580  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  35 00 00 00 5d 40 e0 08      00:14:13.576  WRITE DMA EXT
  ea 00 00 ff 5c 40 a0 08      00:14:13.530  FLUSH CACHE EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: [Оцениваем состояние жёстких дисков при помощи S.M.A.R.T.](https://www.ixbt.com/storage/hdd-smart-testing.shtml)